# Why there is still a race condition even though I call sigsuspend()?

Tags: c, signals

This is the coursework of my class. I'm not sure whether my answer is correct or not. Can someone give me any instruction. In the first question, I can't figure out why there is a race condition, is my explanation wrong?

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void sigHandler(int signo) {
    /* Line C */
}

int main() {
    pid_t pid;
    sigset_t newmask, waitmask, oldmask;

    if ((pid = fork()) == 0) {      // Child
        struct sigaction action;

        sigemptyset(&newmask);
        sigemptyset(&waitmask);
        sigaddset(&newmask, SIGUSR1);
        sigaddset(&waitmask, SIGUSR2);
        sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &newmask, &oldmask);

        action.sa_flags = 0;
        sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);
        action.sa_handler = sigHandler;
        sigaction(SIGUSR2, &action, NULL);
        sigaction(SIGINT, &action, NULL);
        sigaddset(&action.sa_mask, SIGINT);
        sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, NULL);

        /* Line A: critical section */
        sigsuspend(&waitmask);  /* Line B */

    } else {        // Parent
        int stat;
        kill(pid, SIGUSR1);
        kill(pid, SIGUSR2);
        kill(pid, SIGINT);
        pid = wait(&stat);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

1. Although `sigsuspend()` is used here, there is still a race condition. Why?

Since we don't know when the parent process executes first or the child process. If the parent executes first, the parent sends `SIGUSR1`, `SIGUSR2` and `SIGINT` to the child, since `SIGUSR1` is now blocked, the `SIGUSR2` and `SIGINT` will be correctly catched, but we then `sigaddset(&action.sa_mask, SIGINT)`, which means the following line `sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, NULL)` will blocked both `SIGUSR1` and `SIGINT`. Finally, the Line B calls `sigsuspend(&waitmask)`, which will wait signals excepts `SIGUSR2`. But here is my question: since `sigsuspend(&waitmask)` didn't block `SIGUSR1`, why there is still a race condition? Were the `SIGUSR2` and `SIGINT` catched already?

2. Suppose the child process receives (a)`SIGUSR2` at line A, (b)`SIGINT` when blocked at line B, and (c)`SIGUSR1` when `SIGINT` is caught at line C, how the child process' signal mask changes? Explane your answer.

(a) The mask contains `SIGUSR1` (by `sigprocmask()`) and `SIGINT`(by `sigaddset()`).

(b) The mask contains only `SIGUSR2` (by `sigsuspend()`).
After `sigsuspend()`, the mask restore to `SIGUSR1` and `SIGINT`.

(c) The mask contains `SIGINT` and `SIGUSR1`, so it'll block `SIGUSR1`.

3. Suppose the child process receives (a)`SIGUSR1` at line A, (b)`SIGUSR2` when blocked at line B, and (c)`SIGINT` when `SIGUSR1` is caught at line C, how the child process' signal mask changes? Explane your answer.

(a) The mask contains both `SIGUSR1` (by `sigprocmask()`) and `SIGINT` (by `sigaddset()`) and the `SIGUSR1` is blocked.

(b) The mask contains only `SIGUSR2`(by `sigsuspend()`).
   After `sigsuspend()`, the mask restore to `SIGUSR1` and `SIGINT`.

(c) The mask contains `SIGINT` and `SIGUSR1`, so it'll block `SIGINT`.

Comment: For question 1 you are on the right lines. Consider what happens if the `else` part (the parent) runs immediately after the `fork()`, before say even the first `sigemptyset()` in the child.

Comment: amongst other problems with the posted code:  the function: `fork()` actually has 3 returns, not just 2.  <= when an error occurs, ==0 when the child process,  >0 when the parent process.

Comment: it is a poor programming practice for the child process to be executing any of the parent process code.  I.E. at the end of the child process should be a statement similar to: `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);`

Comment: in the current scenario, the parent process should not be in a 'hurry' to start passing signals to the child process until after the child lets the parent know that it is ready to handle the signals.  Such notification is missing from the posted code.

Comment: with the current posted code, the `sighandler()` function is missing the statement: `(void)signo;` so cannot cleanly compile